# How to Get Azure Data Factory to delete a field before send a table to Sink Without using DataFlows

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is it possible to get ADF to delete a field in a table before it is sent to Sink location?

For example if I have a Lookup activity that discovers a field in a table is it possible to for the  copy activity to delete that field in the table before sending the table to sink?

Comment: What type is the Source? If it is SQL, can you use either Query or Stored Procedure to only Select the columns you want?

Comment: Hi @JoelCochran, thanks for reaching out. The source is SQL. However, I was wondering if it might be possible to drop/remove a column without implementing a stored procedure

Comment: Copy activity is a blunt instrument, so you'll need some other way to limit the columns. A Stored Procedure is not required, you should be able to write the SELECT inside the Lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the below sql script in the pre-copy script in the sink settings of copy activity:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
                  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'col1'
                  AND TABLE_SCHEMA='Schema1') 
BEGIN
  ALTER TABLE Table1
    DROP COLUMN col1
 END
```